# 3x2 grid with CSS percentages not working

Tags: html, css

so I've been in web development for a few years so I can usually understand most errors and how to fix them, but recently I have been confused when trying to create responsive websites on the bounds that percentages do not seem to work how I would like them too.

The problem I am having is that I have a 3 x 2 grid which takes up the entire 100% of the screen (1920 x 1080) the widths are set too 33.3% and the height is 50% and they are held in line using the display in-line property.

But when resizing the browser the last tiles on the right are pushed down (like they would if the elements had fixed px and there wasn't enough space) and I was wondering how I could fix this.

This is my CSS:

```
  #main_page_holder {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
 }

#home_navigation_link {
  width: 33.3%;
  height: 50%;
  display: inline-block;
  background-color: #f2f2f2;
}
```

And this is my HTML

```
<div id="main_page_holder">

            <div id="home_navigation_link">
               1
            </div>

            <div id="home_navigation_link">
               1
            </div>

            <div id="home_navigation_link">
               1
            </div>

            <div id="home_navigation_link">
               1
            </div>

            <div id="home_navigation_link">
               1
            </div>

            <div id="home_navigation_link">
               1
            </div>

        </div>
```

Comment: See if **[this great article](http://css-tricks.com/fighting-the-space-between-inline-block-elements/)** can help you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`display:inline-block` is affected by whitespace in the actual HTML structure. Either remove the whitespace or use `float: left`

### [Demo using Float](http://jsfiddle.net/6exkw/)

Also, if you want your grid boxes to actually fill 50% of the screen, you need to apply `height: 100%` to the body/html

```
body, html {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    height: 100%;
}
```

### [Updated demo](http://jsfiddle.net/6exkw/1)

Comment: I've got the 50%, it was a problem with the horizontal boxes being pushed down! fixed now though! thanks :)

Answer (score 0):

In your CSS you need to set the box-sizing property (-moz- prefix is needed, -webkit- also if you want to support Android < 4.0).  I find it helpful to set it for all elements, but you might not want that result.

http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/css3_pr_box-sizing.asp

```
* {
    -moz-box-sizing: border-box;
    -webkit-box-sizing: border-box;
    box-sizing: border-box;
}
```

If you don't want this on all elements, set your responsive area to this box sizing property.  Next, if your elements have margins, they're still outside the box.  You'll want to set margin to 0, or if you want a margin, use a percent.  Play with numbers, but I'd suggest a width of 31% and margin 1%, or possibly width of 32% and margin .5%.  The numbers should add up to 33% using `(2*margin)+width`.

You might want to consider a "normalize.css" which you can get from many places.  Note that not all are the same.  Search for this on Google and read up on different implementations.  Another possibility to consider is Lemonade CSS, see the link below.  You'll notice the first sample block of CSS includes the box sizing property.

http://webdesign.tutsplus.com/articles/build-a-freshly-squeezed-responsive-grid-system--webdesign-14888

Comment: But `box-sizing` will not solve the issue with spaces between inline elements.

Comment: box-sizing was the first correction I added to the fix and it helped fix part of the problem, thanks for the input! :)

Answer (score 0):

With `inline-block`, whitespace matters. To fix the issue, you can remove the whitespace in the html. [jsfilddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Xt4nd/)

```
<div id="main_page_holder"><div id="home_navigation_link">1</div><div id="home_navigation_link">1</div><div id="home_navigation_link">1</div><div id="home_navigation_link">1</div><div id="home_navigation_link">1</div><div id="home_navigation_link">1</div></div>
```

Comment: Fantastic, I've used a collation of helpful tips from this thread including this one, thanks man! :)

Answer (score 0):

I believe the reason for this problem is something to do with the *inline-block* display style. When you are using inline-block, you have spaces between the elements with inline or inline-block styles. This is just like you have spaces between words. You can solve this by setting the font-size of 'main_page_holder' to 0;

Comment: I replaced inline-block with clear and float and I'm having no more problems, thanks buddy! :)